# how to check entered regex pattern and example are correct or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match

I have two textbox in my form. First for regex pattern, and second is for input text.

I am try to check enter regex pattern and entered text matches or not.

This is [my simple attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/NxFCg/1/).

And this is working demo:

```
'01-01-2012'.match( /\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/ )
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NxFCg/3/)

Any solution for my query?

Comment: I don't understand your problem

Comment: @Lonely i am enter one regex pattern on textbox like:- `/\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/` and in second texbox enter date `01-01-2012` ->valid enter `2012-01-01` -> invalid

Comment: Understood and
even we have to check, it is valid date or not
like we don't have date like 42-34-1234 etc
interesting problem

Answer (score 1):

Use `var pattern = new RegExp($('#pattern').val());`. In this case you have to enter pattern without slashes, like `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}` (or you can make a check for their presence and cut them).

Though you can create regexp in your code like `var pattern = /\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/`, but when you get a pattern from the input field and assign it to a variable, JavaScript will not parse it as a regular expression, it just will assign a string to a variable. And because of this you have to explicitly create a RegExp object and pass this string to its constructor, so interpreter will create regular expression from it.

Answer (score 0):

The `match()` on string takes a regexp object, however you are passing in a string. This will be converted to a regexp, unfortunately it will process the string some what, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp

If you enter `\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}` in the text box it will work.

If you need the system to work with normal regular expressions you need to process the string and remove the `/` at either end and then escape the `\`.